# Using the length function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to check if my variable only has a length of one.

I do this like so:

```
var n = new Date();
$scope.h = n.getHours();
$scope.m = n.getMinutes();

console.log($scope.h.length) // returns undefined

if($scope.h.length < 2 && $scope.m.length < 2 ) {
    $scope.hm = $scope.h * 10 + "" + $scope.m * 10;
    console.log($scope.hm);
}
```

but $scope.h.length returns undefined. Why? 
How should i do this better?

Comment: you are trying to check length for integer thats the reason you are getting undefined getHours() returns integer

Comment: Because getHours() retuens an integer,YOu cannoy access length property on an integer

Comment: What is an alternative?

Comment: what are you trying here if($scope.h.length < 2 && $scope.m.length < 2 ) can u explain ur condition then it can be said whether u need ur length condition or not?

Comment: As @bhanu.cs said it returns an integer. Have a look at plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/ZC6g7gOd2JZapzWRH1qm?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using [`Date.prototype.getHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) thta return an `integer number` thus you cannot directly use `.length` on it.

The solution is to use the `toString()` function before taking the length

OR

You can use `= "" + h`

```js
var n = new Date();
var h = n.getHours();
var m = n.getMinutes();

var hString = "" + h;
var mString = m.toString();

console.log(hString.length);
console.log(mString.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to check length in your case.

```
if($scope.h < 10 && $scope.m < 10 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

getHours() returns a number. Numbers do not have a length property. Try converting your number to a string first with $scope.h.toString().